# how to add add heading tag to selected text using TinyMCE

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I need to add the h1 tag for selected text using tinyMCE. i use the following code

```
tinymce.init({
            selector:"td",
            inline: true,
            menubar:false,
            statusbar: false,
            branding: false,
            browser_spellcheck: true,
            toolbar: 'undo redo bold  italic | formatselect fontselect fontsizeselect | forecolor backcolor | alignleft aligncenter alignright | superscript subscript | bullist numlist | link | code',
            plugins: ['code','textcolor','link']
        });
```

Comment: The Formats option already has a way to make something an H1 - does that not solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your own TinyMCE plugin to achieve this. Take a look at TinyMCE's documentation on the subject (https://www.tinymce.com/docs/advanced/creating-a-plugin/) and this question ([Get the Highlighted/Selected text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379120/get-the-highlighted-selected-text)) about getting selected text